# Finding a way to navigate Windows File explorer, using sikulix #Automation

Tags: scripting, web-crawler, robotframework, sikuli

I'm downloading a large amount of PDF's from a embedded pdf viewer. Hence why I'm using the the robot framework in combination with Sikuli and Selenium.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnSRW.png)
I've successfully been able to hit the download button, but the next task that I cannot figure out is changing directory's in file explorer, or clicking the save button. Any suggestions?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgNeh.png)
(Because of the embedded pdf viewer, I cannot download pdf via link)

I've tried taking screen shots of directory search bars and save button for Sikuli.

Answer (score 0):

After the Save-dialog is open, the field having the filename is selected.
So you might simply type the full path to the save-folder plus a suitable filename.

If you want to keep the given filename, just `type(Key.LEFT)`, which puts the cursor before the given filename. Now you can also type the save-path:
`type("\\root\\folder\\SaveHere\\")`

Finally simply `type("Key.ENTER")` which should trigger the save button.

This is RaiMan from SikuliX